# dorpdownlist SelectedIndexChanged breakpoint not trigged

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-4.0

I have a breakpoint on a dropdownlist control on my asp.net page. But it is not activated when I select an item from the ListBox. What am I missing here?

```
onselectedindexchanged="ddlProjectSearchID_SelectedIndexChanged"  

protected void ddlProjectSearchID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "key", string.Format("alert('{0}');", DateTime.Now.Day), true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` on DropDown.

Comment: I knew it was something ridiculously simple. Thanks